# Problems GROUP BY SQL Server HIBERNATE

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpql, sql-server-profiler

I can not solve the error

```
Column 'cohort.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained 
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

The log in my opinion is correct, if you do not use aggregate functions and grouping, then the query is working, but does not perform grouping.

```
@Query("select i, sum(r.dose) from Inspection i left join fetch i.cohort c 
left join fetch c.parent left join fetch i.user left join i.personal p left 
join i.result r where i.id in :inspection GROUP by i")
```

Tell us what the problem may be. I use SQL Server to be more recent 2008

That's what arrives in SQL Server Profiler

```
 exec sp_executesql N'select inspection0_.id as col_0_0_, sum(result5_.dose) 
as col_1_0_, cohort1_.id as id1_4_1_, cohort2_.id as id1_4_2_, personal3_.id 
as id1_36_3_, inspection0_.id as id1_28_0_, inspection0_.cohort_id as 
cohort_11_28_0_, inspection0_.date as date2_28_0_, 
inspection0_.exposure_time as exposure3_28_0_, inspection0_.height as 
height4_28_0_, inspection0_.intake as intake5_28_0_, 
inspection0_.next_measurement as next_mea6_28_0_, inspection0_.note as 
note7_28_0_, inspection0_.personal_id as persona12_28_0_, inspection0_.unit 
as unit8_28_0_, inspection0_.updated as updated9_28_0_, inspection0_.user_id 
as user_id13_28_0_, inspection0_.weight as weight10_28_0_, cohort1_.code as 
code2_4_1_, cohort1_.name as name3_4_1_, cohort1_.parent_id as 
parent_i6_4_1_, cohort1_.type as type4_4_1_, cohort1_.updated as 
updated5_4_1_, cohort1_.user_id as user_id7_4_1_, cohort2_.code as 
code2_4_2_, cohort2_.name as name3_4_2_, cohort2_.parent_id as 
parent_i6_4_2_, cohort2_.type as type4_4_2_, cohort2_.updated as 
updated5_4_2_, cohort2_.user_id as user_id7_4_2_, personal3_.birth_date as 
birth_da2_36_3_, personal3_.first_name as first_na3_36_3_, 
personal3_.last_name as last_nam4_36_3_, personal3_.middle_name as 
middle_n5_36_3_, personal3_.sex as sex6_36_3_, personal3_.tab_number as 
tab_numb7_36_3_, personal3_.transfer_id as transfer8_36_3_ 
from inspection 
inspection0_ left outer join cohort cohort1_ on 
inspection0_.cohort_id=cohort1_.id left outer join cohort cohort2_ on 
cohort1_.parent_id=cohort2_.id left outer join personal personal3_ on 
inspection0_.user_id=personal3_.id left outer join person person4_ on 
inspection0_.personal_id=person4_.id left outer join inspection_result 
result5_ on inspection0_.id=result5_.inspection_id where inspection0_.id in 
(@P0) 
group by inspection0_.id order by inspection0_.id asc ',N'@P0 int',1
```

Comment: you have "select i" and "Inspection i" so your table alias is i while you should be selecting a column like i.columnName (unless I am totally confused).

Comment: Add cohort.id in SELECT clause or alias it

Comment: That query looks very incomplete. Where are you `ON` clauses??? Why is `fetch` preceding your schema (?) names for some of your tables? Why do the tables `i.user` and `c.parent` not have aliases, and the others do? What is `i` in your `SELECT` statement (as @nsawaya mentions).

Comment: In this query, I did not use "ON" since this request worked in the H2 database. Can you tell me how to properly use "ON" in this case?

Comment: The grouping should take place by "id inspection" if you use select i.id, sum (r.dose) from Inspection i, I get an error "Error creating bean with name 'inspectionController'"

Comment: There have been many reports of the trouble hibernate has on grouping by entities (eg [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1615) and [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2436)). I'm not sure what the current status is (or what version you are using). You will probably have to type out the query specifically. That means specifying all attributes from `i` in the select and the `group by`.

Comment: I use hibernate:5.0.12.Final